# NativeScript Angular project 'tns run android' gives errors

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I created a project using the following command:

```
ng new -c=@nativescript/schematics project-name --shared
```

When I run `tns run android`, I get the following errors:

```
platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/mergeDebugAssets/out/app/tns_modules/zone.js/lib/zone-spec/long-stack-trace.ts(25,10): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/mergeDebugAssets/out/app/tns_modules/zone.js/lib/zone.ts(632,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'AmbientZone'.
platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/app/tns_modules/rxjs/src/operator/catch.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/operator/catch'.
```

These are just sample errors. There are so many of these kind.

I tried;

- Removing node_modules folder and run `npm install`
- Removing platforms/android folder
- Updating NativeScript(5.1.0) and Angular CLI()
- Removing /users/username/.gradle folder and let it reinstall
- Reinstalling Nodejs
- Installing rxjs-compat which only solves rxjs-compat related errors

Nothing worked so far.

```
ng --version
```

- Angular CLI: 7.2.1+
- Angular: 7.1.4
- @angular-devkit/architect 0.12.1 (cli-only)
- @angular-devkit/core 7.0.7
- @angular-devkit/schematics 7.0.7
- @ngtools/webpack 7.1.4
- @schematics/angular 7.0.7
- @schematics/update 0.12.1 (cli-only)
- rxjs 6.3.3
- typescript 3.1.6
- webpack 4.27.1

`tns --version`

5.1.0

Comment: Which version of Angular you are using?

Comment: try installing `rxjs-compat`

Comment: Installing rxjs-compat only solves rxjs-compat related errors. There must be some other problem underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [the issue here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/916)

Basically, remove the `tns_modules` folder from `platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/mergeDebugAssets/out/app/tns_modules/`

It is apparently caused by `npm link` command I used somewhere.